# How to select a field when it is not in GroupBy clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I do not want to group by "**BimeName.IssueDate**" field in this select and I do not know how to do it.
If I don't specify this field in GroupBy clause I will get an error.

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column 'BimeName.IssueDate' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an 
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please help me!

```
SELECT
        BimeName.IssueDate,
        sum(BimeName.Premium) as Permium,
        TypeOfInsurances.TypeOfInsurance + ' ' +
        InsuranceKinds.KindOfInsurance as KindOfInsurance,
        InsuranceAgents.NameOfInsurance,
        InsuranceAgents.Representation + ' ' +
        InsuranceAgents.AgentCode as Agent
from    
        BimeName
        Inner Join InsuranceKinds ON InsuranceKinds.Id = BimeName.KindOfInsuranceId
        Inner Join TypeOfInsurances ON TypeOfInsurances.Id = InsuranceKinds.TypeOfInsuranceId
        Inner Join InsuranceAgents ON InsuranceAgents.Id = TypeOfInsurances.InsuranceAgentId
where   
        BimeName.IssueDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2017-01-30'
group by InsuranceAgents.Representation, InsuranceAgents.NameOfInsurance, InsuranceAgents.AgentCode  , BimeName.IssueDate  , TypeOfInsurances.TypeOfInsurance , InsuranceKinds.KindOfInsurance
```

Comment: I want sum Premium filed with group by on another fields. thanks

Comment: Well then just take out the date from your select clause

Comment: The problem here is because Date is in my where syntax. please review my code!

Comment: Read the error message: Column 'BimeName.IssueDate' is invalid in the **select list**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave out the date field from select, if you, like you said, don't need it.

```
SELECT
        sum(BimeName.Premium) as Permium,
        TypeOfInsurances.TypeOfInsurance + ' ' +
        InsuranceKinds.KindOfInsurance as KindOfInsurance,
        InsuranceAgents.NameOfInsurance,
        InsuranceAgents.Representation + ' ' +
        InsuranceAgents.AgentCode as Agent
from    
        BimeName
        Inner Join InsuranceKinds ON InsuranceKinds.Id = BimeName.KindOfInsuranceId
        Inner Join TypeOfInsurances ON TypeOfInsurances.Id = InsuranceKinds.TypeOfInsuranceId
        Inner Join InsuranceAgents ON InsuranceAgents.Id = TypeOfInsurances.InsuranceAgentId
where   
        BimeName.IssueDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2017-01-30'
group by 
        InsuranceAgents.Representation, 
        InsuranceAgents.NameOfInsurance, 
        InsuranceAgents.AgentCode, 
        TypeOfInsurances.TypeOfInsurance, 
        InsuranceKinds.KindOfInsurance
```

You can have fields in where clause that are not in group by.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense. Imagine it has different values for field **BimeName.IssueDate** in a same group, so which value must be selected for that category? should think about it again.